# How do I parse through java source code and not store blank lines?

Tags: java, parsing, java.util.scanner

This is my method for adding each line of code:

```
    public static void String(){
    File f = new File("src/testClass.java");
    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
        s.useDelimiter("\\n");
            while(s.hasNextLine()){
                String st = s.next();
                if(!st.equals("\\p{Space}")) System.out.println(st);
                }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the testClass.java

```
public class testClass {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int someNum = 1; //comment
        String someStr = "haha";
        /* final double pi = 3.14159;
         * 
         */
    }

    public static void uselessMethod(int someNum){
        boolean isUseless1 = true;
    }   
}
```

When I use this class to test my parser, it doesn't skip over the blank space after the brace underneath the closing bracket for main. What needs to be done to not get it to be stored? What is the more appropriate if statement to get it to not store that blank line, while acknowledging that it is a line rather than skipping over it completely? I want to keep track of the line number while not storing the blank lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [`matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) method instead of `equals()`:

```
if(!st.matches("^\\p{Space}*$")) System.out.println(st);
```

I've also modified your regular expression a little bit. It should now exclude all lines that are empty or contain only whitespace.

Comment: Thank you. That made it not store that line.

Comment: Also, I used `if( st.equals("\\p{Digit}"))` to check if the next iteration is purely numerical, but my program keeps adding the integer anyways. What's the right way to ask if st equals a digit?

Answer (score 0):

I usually just skip empty line:

```
public static List<String> fileToList(String patch) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(patch));
        String line ="";
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            /*
             * Just skip empty line
             */
            if (line.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            } else {
                result.add(line);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```